# Compute integral of exponential with polynomial division in argument

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I'm trying to calculate this integral

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{|x|}\exp\left(-\frac{a + bx^4}{cx^2}\right)dx $$

As a start, I thought maybe integration by parts was my best bet, so I looked into finding just the integral of the exponent part:

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{a + bx^4}{cx^2}\right)dx$$
But even that is looking quite difficult. I've tried dividing the polynomial, as suggested  in this [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435849/an-improper-integral-of-an-exponential-with-rational-fraction-argument) but doesn't really help in this problem.

Is it hopeless to find a closed-form solution for this?

Comment: Why do you want the indefinite integral?

Comment: In the end I'm trying to compute a function f(a,b,c) = integral in question, so I'm interested in the anti-derivative and not a specific numerical evaluation.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The indefinite integral would be a function $f(a,b,c,x)$ and would only be $f(a,b,c)$ with bounds to make it a definite integral.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I just edited my original question

Comment: The second integral is a simple application of Glasser's master theorem and evaluates to $$\sqrt{\frac{c\pi}{b}}\exp\left(-\frac{2}{c}\sqrt{\frac{b^3}{a}}\right)$$ The original integral is a little more challenging but I think you could apply the same theorem by using Feynman trick first.

Comment: Couple things to note, too. $c$ is redundant so denote $f(a,b,c)=g\left(\frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{c}\right)$. And the substitution $x\leftrightarrow\frac{1}{x}$ proves $g(a,b)=g(b,a)$

Comment: Using the [integral representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32) (eq. 10.32.10) your first integral is the modified Bessel function $K_0$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks a lot for pointing to Glasser's master theorem (I didn't know of its existence). Your answer was almost correct. Here's the result, which I have verified numerically using WolframAlpha:

$$\sqrt{\frac{c\pi}{b}}\exp\left(-\frac{2}{c}\sqrt{ab} \right)$$

I'll think about what you said of using Feynman's trick to solve the full integral

Comment: @Sal I verified your answer numerically and I convinced myself that the integral in question is equal to the function you pointed to, but do you have some hints on how to prove that's true? i.e., going from original integral to something including $K_0$

Comment: With $c$ set to one by absorbing it into other constants, let $x=(a/b)^{1/4}u$, then the exponential becomes $-\sqrt{ab}(u^{-2}+u^2)$. Then let $u^2=e^t$ to recover the more familiar $e^{\cosh}$ integral form of $K_0$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to calculate the second integral in the case that $a, b>0$.

Next we will focus on the special case that $b=1$. Note that by letting $x=\sqrt{b}y$ and change the variable, we can easily reduce to this special case.

Note that when $a=0$, the integral is easy to compute (that's the Gauss integral). So we can attempt to differentiate over $a$, and see if we can get a differential equation.

Since the integrand is an even function, we only need to consider the integral over $[0, \infty)$. Let
$$
I(a) = \int_0^\infty \exp \left(-\frac{a+bx^4}{cx^2}\right)\,dx = \int_0^\infty \exp \left[-\frac{1}{c}\left(\frac{a}{x^2} + x^2\right)\right]\,dx.
$$
By taking derivative over $a$ and changing the variable by $(-1/x^2)\,dx = d(1/x)$, we get
$$
I'(a) = \int_0^\infty -\frac{1}{cx^2}\exp \left[-\frac{1}{c}\left(\frac{a}{x^2} + x^2\right)\right]\,dx = -\frac{1}{c}\int_0^\infty\exp\left[-\frac{1}{c}\left(ax^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right]\,dx.
$$
Change the variable again by letting $y=\sqrt{a}x$, then we get
$$
I'(a) = -\frac{1}{c}\int_0^\infty\exp\left[-\frac{1}{c}\left(y^2+\frac{a}{y^2}\right)\right]\sqrt{a}\,dy = -\frac{\sqrt{a}}{c}I(a).
$$
Next we only need to solve the differential equation with the known initial value $I(0)$.